# when to use scripts in xml

Tags: xml, apache-flex

being somewhat new to xml, I see examples where scripts are embedded within xml.  Unless it's xhtml, I don't understand why you would mark a section as a script.  For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="300" height="150" styleName="userstory">

    <fx:Style source="styles/styles.css"/>

    <fx:Text x="5" y="5" width="275" height="135" text="{userStoryText}" fontFamily="notes" fontSize="24"/>

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public var userStoryText:String;

            private function handleDown(e:Event):void {
                this.startDrag();
            }

            private function handleUp(e:Event):void {
                this.stopDrag();
            }

            override protected function createChildren():void {
                super.createChildren();
                super.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,handleDown);
                super.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,handleUp);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Canvas>
```

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/644918

The above being purely xml, why would you use a script?  Only certain languages make sense -- just javascript and adobe flex?

thanks,

Thufir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i am not wrong, you are asking why
>   mix code with XML?

I think you are bit confused, you can have your actionScript code in a seperate file and call them in your main MXML component file or use your actionscript code inside your MXML component itself.

> You use two languages to write Flex
>   applications: MXML and ActionScript.
>   MXML is an XML markup language that
>   you use to lay out user interface
>   components. You also use MXML to
>   declaratively define nonvisual aspects
>   of an application, such as access to
>   data sources on the server and data
>   bindings between user interface
>   components and data sources on the
>   server.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=mxml_2.html

Let me know if you have anymore queries, if your question is still un answered.

Comment: +1 for quoting docs; and being much more elegant than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure completely what you're asking.

Flex is a mix of ActionScript and MXML.  MXML is an XML dialect, as you allude to a bit.

The Script tag is a way to include ActionScript code inside an MXML Component.  There is a lot you can do in ActionScript that can't be done in MXML.  From your example the script overrides a method and defines a public property on the method.  Those two things can't be done in MXML.

The event handlers could, in theory, be implemented in-line in MXML; but it gets very cumbersome if your event handler has more than one line, or any conditional logic.  I don't think it is possible to do comparisons  with '>', '<', or '&' in MXML.

How else would you do it?

Comment: Ok, yes, I'm aware that MXML is a dialect, and sorta understand namespaces.  My "bigger" question is why mix code and markup?  Why not just have plain-text .foo (or, in this case, .flx) code files?  That's how javascript, ruby, etc work.  Why mix scripts with xml?

Comment: Do JavaScript or Ruby support two different, simultaneous, languages?  I know nothing about Ruby, but JavaScript is just JavaScript.  In an HTML page the JavaScript can be separate, or in code blocks, or in-line.  That's not much different than Flex.  Flex is ActionScript and MXML. In Flex, you are more than welcome to code in All ActionScript; they are usually put in .as files.  Under the hood, MXML is converted into ActionScript before it is compiled o a SWF; there is even a compiler argument to store that converted code to disk so you can view it.

Comment: I was asking about the pros and cons of code being seperate, in code blocks, or in-line.  Not the best question, but answered well.